# Separating multiple email entries in HTML email input on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have written a small web application in Node.js that includes a single line where users can enter one or more email addresses separated by a comma character:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>eHaW Email</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>

    <form action="/createMsg" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group mb-3 mt-3 ms-1 me-1">
        <label for="text" class="control-label">From:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from" 
               placeholder="Enter your name" name="from" 
               required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3 mt-3 ms-1 me-1">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">To:</label>
        <input type="email" multiple class="form-control" id="to" 
               placeholder="Enter 1 or more email addresses, separated by commas ','" name="email" required />
        <button type="button" id="addComma" onclick="insertComma">,</button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mType" 
               name="mType" readonly hidden required >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-3 mt-3 ms-1 me-1">
        <label for="msg" class="control-label">Message:</label>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="message" 
               placeholder="Enter the message you want to send here..." 
               name="msg" rows="5" onkeyup="countChars(this);" required ></textarea>
        <p class="text-secondary" id="charNum">1000 characters remaining</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-auto" style="width:350px" align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <p> </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" align="right">
        <form action="/" method="GET">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col" align="left">
        <form action="/status" method="GET">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Status</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  document.getElementById("addComma").addEventListner("click", (e) => {
    const item = document.getElementById("to");
    item.value = += ", ";
    item.focus();
  });

  function countChars(obj){
    let maxLength = 1000;
    let strLength = obj.value.length;
    let charRemain = maxLength - strLength;
    
    if(charRemain < 0){
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">You have exceeded the limit of '+maxLength+' characters</span>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = charRemain+' characters remaining';
    }
    document.getElementById("mType").value = "Email";
  }

  function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
```

I have a problem when someone with an iPhone wants to enter more than one email address, because the email entry keypad on an iPhone does not include a comma character.  If the user tries to use a space character as a separator, the code above declares the entry invalid.

Is there any way to specify another separator character?

Comment: If the stupid iPhone is not respecting the `multiple` attribute, then your only reasonable alternative is to specify some more permissive type other than `type="email"` that provides an input keyboard with more characters including comma and do your own validation.  There is no other separator character that the keyboard allows that isn't also a valid email address character.  Or, you could make your widget and control things that way.

Comment: The only other idea I had was a button that would somehow add an additional email field to my entry form.  But I don't know if it is possible to add a field to an html form dynamically, or how to do it...  Pointers to this or alternate solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `comma` button to your form that would insert a `", "` to the end of the `to` field.

HTML:

```
<button id="addComma">Comma</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("addComma").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const item = document.getElementById("to");
    item.value += ", ";
    item.focus();
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("addComma").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const item = document.getElementById("to");
    item.value += ", ";
    item.focus();
});
```

```html
<input type="email" multiple class="form-control" id="to" 
         placeholder="Enter 1 or more email addresses, separated by commas ','" 
         name="email" required />
 
 <button id="addComma">Comma</button>
```

---

Your attempt to implement this has multiple problems:

1. Remove the `onclick="insertComma"`.  There is no function named `insertComma()` and you're already adding the client event listener a different way.
2. Change this `item.value = += ", ";` to this `item.value += ", ";`.  I don't know why you added the extra `=`, but that's invalid syntax.
3. Fix the spelling of `.addEventListener` to look like this.

In many cases, you should be able to see your errors by looking in the browser console when this code executes and see what error it is complaining about.  That's all I did here to diagnose your code.

Comment: Thats a GREAT idea!  Let me see if I can make it work and I'll be back...  Bob

Comment: I love the idea, but am struggling to make it work.  Please bear with me, I'm a novice when it comes to Javascript.  I don't think the new click event is running as the new 'addComma' button doesn't seem to do anything.  I extend the code snippet in my original post to show more of my code and how I attempted your fix...

Comment: @user3763748 - See what I added to the end of my answer.  You had three coding mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my entry errors.  Your browser console tip was also very helpful.  It is working now and all I have to do are a few layout adjustments.